# Cube map filtering for VSM shadows

Tags: opengl, 3d, metal

I render the distances around a point light on the six faces of a cube map. Then I blur the faces of the cube map in order to perform **Variance Shadow Maps**. The problem is that there are artefacts in the final image because the blurring near the edges of each face of the cube map is not accurate because **the pixels near the edges do not count for samples from its neighbour faces**.

So, instead of rendering to each face using a 90 degrees FOV I use a wider FOV that depends on the blurring kernel size and render to a texture. Then I blur the texture and keep only the part that matches the 90 degrees FOV of the cube map face and copy it to the face of the cube map. Unfortunately although the artefacts are fewer there still exist. Can anyone elaborate on this? Am I missing something? Maybe I am not correctly adjusting the wider FOV correctly. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: If you use compute shaders to blur faces, why can't you just take some samples for blurring from neighbouring faces rather than widen the fov.

Comment: @EgorShkorov I use a high performance Gaussian blur implementation for 2D. Blurring a cube map is a lot slower if you want to get quality results because you want lots of samples. This is not an option for me unfortunately.